# Matplotlib 2 plots on the same figure with separate sizes

Tags: python, matplotlib

I need to plot 1 **large** plot at the top of a figure, and then a **small** plot **UNDERNEATH** it. Currently I have this code:

```
times = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temps1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temps2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
temps3 = [100, 200, 300, 400]


plt.subplot(211)
plt.plot(times, temps1, c="#ff7f0e", label="1")
plt.plot(times, temps2, c="#2ca02c", label="2")
plt.plot(times, temps3, c="#1f77b4", label="3")



labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

width = 0.35       # the width of the bars: can also be len(x) sequence


plt.subplot(212)
plt.bar(labels, men_means, width, label='Men')
plt.bar(labels, women_means, width, bottom=men_means,
       label='Women')


plt.show()
```

and this correctly plots the graphs underneath eachother. However, I can't set the size of the second figure (the one underneath) I need it to not be the same size as the other, and I have tried many variations such as changing it to `fig,ax = ..` and then changing the fig, this didn't work and many other variations. There are some that work with plots next to eachother but not underneath. How can I independently change the size of each of these plots?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure if the size of each graph is what you want, so I created them in the appropriate ratio.' Use 'GridSpec()' to determine the number of graphs in rows and columns, and specify the row ratio and column ratio as parameters. Once the placement is determined, associate the graphs to it.Kindly refer to [this](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.gridspec.GridSpec.html).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

times = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temps1 = [1, 2, 3, 4]
temps2 = [10, 20, 30, 40]
temps3 = [100, 200, 300, 400]

fig = plt.figure(figsize=(10, 8))
gs = plt.GridSpec(nrows=2, ncols=1, height_ratios=[3, 1])
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(gs[0, 0])
ax1.plot(times, temps1, c="#ff7f0e", label="1")
ax1.plot(times, temps2, c="#2ca02c", label="2")
ax1.plot(times, temps3, c="#1f77b4", label="3")

labels = ['G1', 'G2', 'G3', 'G4', 'G5']
men_means = [20, 35, 30, 35, 27]
women_means = [25, 32, 34, 20, 25]

width = 0.35

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(gs[1, 0])
ax2.bar(labels, men_means, width, label='Men')
ax2.bar(labels, women_means, width, bottom=men_means, label='Women')

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: That's awesome, thanks! I have another somewhat related question(s) if that's alright, 1 being what part of the code do I alter to make the second plot differ in size, and also, this is kind of off-topic, but if I have a bar graph, can I (instead of values such as 20) have them plot their height against a string, for example "Object3", "Object2" and it goes in that order but the y scale is not numbers, but that instead. anyway thanks for the awesome answer!

Comment: The place to determine the composition ratio is `height_ratios=[3,1]` here. If the overall height is 4, the top row is 3, which is 75%. The rest will be 25%.

Comment: You mean you want to add an annotation? You want to calculate the length of a string and use that as the y-axis value? I'm not sure I understand.